# Why the base class object is not able to provide its member functions and members in Generics base class constraints

Tags: c#, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Rextester
{
    public class PhoneNumber 
    {
        public  PhoneNumber()
        {
        }
            public  PhoneNumber(string n, string num) 
        {
            Member = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Member.Add(n,num);          
        }

        public void Add(string n, string num)
        {
            Member = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Member.Add(n,num);
        }
        public Dictionary<string,string> Member { get; set; }

    }
    class FriendsPhoneNumbers : PhoneNumber 
    {
        public FriendsPhoneNumbers (){}
        public FriendsPhoneNumbers (string n, string num, bool wk) :
        base(n, num)
        {
            IsWorkNumber = wk;
        }
        public bool IsWorkNumber { get; private set; }
    }
    class PhoneList<T> where T : PhoneNumber
    {
        T[] phList;
        int end;
        public PhoneList()
        {
            phList = new T[10];
            end = 0;
        }
        public bool Add(T newEntry)
        {
            if(end == 10) return false;
            phList[end] = newEntry;
            end++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PhoneNumber pnm=new PhoneNumber("Hii","123");
            pnm.Add("Hello","456");
            Console.WriteLine("pnm count: "+pnm.Member.Count);
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> k in pnm.Member)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k.Key+": "+k.Value);  
            }

            PhoneList<PhoneNumber> p2=new PhoneList<PhoneNumber>();
            p2.Add(new PhoneNumber("Hii!","789"));
            p2.Add(new PhoneNumber ("Hello","4565"));
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> k in p2.Member)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k.Key+": "+k.Value);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Error:PhoneList' does not contain a definition for 'Member' and no extension method 'Member' 
   accepting a first argument of type PhoneList' 
   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. How the property dictionary "Member = new Dictionary()" can be declared in the class "Phonenumber" such that both "Add" method and constructor in the class use it and give pnm.count value=2 in Main method.

Comment: Your design choices seem a bit peculiar to me. I'd think once your design made more sense, you'll see things are far easier then what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Though the clas "PhoneNumber" it is a base type constraint for generic class 'PhoneList" , I want to use it as normal class in Main method.

Comment: Agree with @YuvalItzchakov here. Suggest you look at relationships for this model. Is a Friend a PhoneNumber?

Answer (score 0):

p2 is a PhoneList

```
PhoneList<PhoneNumber> p2=new PhoneList<PhoneNumber>();
```

PhoneList does not have a member property so this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> k in p2.Member)
```

Makes no sense and quite rightly throws an error. I think you want PhoneList to inherit from Collection as it is a custom collection with some Add logic, that is exactly what Collection is for. Then you will have a class you can actuall pull items back from and then you can ask for their Memeber property.

So it looks like this:

```
public class PhoneList<T> : Collection<T> where T : PhoneNumber
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (this.Count() < 10)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);       
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't return true, but you never use the return value in the code. Then you can write this:

```
        foreach(var k in p2.SelectMany(x => x.Member))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k.Key+": "+k.Value);  
        }
```

That gives you all the numbers.

As for your initializing Member you probably want to do this:

```
public class PhoneNumber 
{
    public  PhoneNumber()
    {
         Member = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public  PhoneNumber(string n, string num) : this()
    {            
        Member.Add(n,num);          
    }

    public void Add(string n, string num)
    {
        Member = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Member.Add(n,num);
    }

    public Dictionary<string,string> Member { get; private set; }

}
```

It always gets initialized whatever constructor you call and can be reset from outside the class. You would get the count by:

```
pnm.Members.Count;
```

Comment: PhoneList will inherit property 'Member' from base class 'PhoneNumber' so it should be available, for example in:- PhoneList<Friend> plist = new PhoneList<Friend>(), plist is of type PhoneList but the property 'Member' is available for plist and Friend is derived from PhoneList.

Comment: PhoneNumber is not the base class for PhoneList, "PhoneList<T> where T : PhoneNumber" means the "T" is PhoneNumber (or a subclass) not that PhoneList Inherits from it. You are confusing generic constraints with inheritance. It doesn't make any sense for it to inherit PhoneNumber any way, inheritance is and "is a" relationship, is Phone list a PhoneNumber, not it isn't. Your PhoneList class isn't much use as is all it does is add values to an internal array, you can't retrieve anything from it.